# iOS Custom Document Type Icons

Tags: ios, icons

Can anyone explain to me the difference between the UTTypeSize64IconFile and UITypeSize320IconFile keys under UTExportedTypeDeclarations, and CFBundleTypeIconFiles in CFBundleDocumentTypes?  I've found a few places in the docs that talk about CFBundleTypeIconFiles (e.g. here: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/FileManagement/Conceptual/DocumentInteraction_TopicsForIOS/Articles/RegisteringtheFileTypesYourAppSupports.html), but the only explanation of UTTypeSize64IconFile I can find is:

> The name of the 64 x 64 pixel icon resource file (located in the app’s bundle) to associate 
>   with this UTI. You should include this key only for types that your app exports.

which doesn't really illuminate things for me.